# Enable HTTP/2 on WCF and Web API

Tags: c#, iis, http2

I tried to enable the HTTP/2 on my IIS 10. i used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis) tutorial in order to do that. after enabling HTTP/2 i tested my server with various clients and even online websites like these:

1. https://http2.pro
2. https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test

all result indicates that server supports the HTTP/2. when i log the request with my IIS i can see the protocol version is 2 but when i log the request on my application (wcf and web api) it shows HTTP/1.1!!
now i wonder what is the problem? do i miss something or what?

***NOTE***

1. during the test i realize i have to restart whole IIS after disabling and enabling HTTP/2 feature. which founded little odd.
2. when i send the HTTP/2 request with fidller i get 505 error.
3. for internal loging i use log4net and log the `SERVER_PROTOCOL` like this: `HttpContext.Current?.Request?.Params["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]`
4. this my api if you want test it: [here](https://application.billingsystem.ayantech.ir/WebServices/Core.svc/ElectricityBillInquiry)

Comment: You may want to delete cookies between retries.  The server may be using the old cookie to determine if you are using HTTP/1 or HTTP/2.  I like using a sniffer 
output from fiddler and checking first request to make sure all the HTTP/2 features are correct.  The sniffer output will give a lot more info than log4net.  I would first get fiddler working and then c#.  The headers in the working fiddler and c# should be the same.

Comment: unfortunately it looks like fiddler doesnt support the HTTP/2. but i monitor the request with Firefox network and its HTTP/2. as i mention every things look OK before application server but after that its http/1.1.!!!

Comment: I was looking at differences in http/2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) and see two significant changes 1) Doesn't support http 1.1 chunk mode 2) Uses TLS 1.2 or later (which is TLS 1.3).  The fiddler sniffer features should work with any connection (although the decoding of new protocols may not get decoded).  The fiddler connection tools will not work if it is sending chunk mode 1.1 or using older TLS 1.1.  I don't like using general terms like "doesn't support the http/2".  Rather say it doesn't support the newer features because you still will work with stream mode (not chunked).

Comment: Windows/IIS might support HTTP/2, but a web framework can still reject it. I don't think old WCF or ASP.NET Web API supports HTTP/2, and you should try ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I tried your site it shows that it is using http/2 protocol you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTC4q.png). which os you are using? also carefully read the http/2 document it mentions that In a few cases, HTTP/2 can't be used in combination with other features. In these situations, Windows will fall back to HTTP/1.1 and continue the transaction. This may involve negotiating HTTP/1.1 during the handshake, or sending an error code to the client instructing it to retry over an HTTP/1.1 connection.

Comment: you could use a network monitor to check a handshake is happen between the client and server or not.

Comment: @LexLi you mean onle .net core supports the http/2? are you sure?

Comment: thank you dear @JalpaPanchal. I'm using windows server 2016. but i didn't understand. now my api works or not? in the iis log i can see the http/2 connections but in the application logs its http/1.1!!

Comment: @JalpaPanchal network monitors show the http/2 connection.

Comment: it means your site is using http 2

Comment: but in the application layer i recive the reuests as http/1.1. it means http/2 connections are between web server(iis) and client. and the application(web api or wcf) doesn't get involved. is this true?

Comment: You might read more from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0#http2-support

Comment: thanks dear @LexLi. but the post indicates .net core supports http/2. i cant find any references that shows wcf or web api doesn't support http/2.

Comment: In .NET Framework 4.6.0 Microsoft announced support for HTTP/2. So the .NET Framework 4.6.0 & 4.6.1 supports HTTP/2.Enabling SSL for ASP.NET Core Application: Now go to your Visual Studio – select your project from the solution explorer window (The ASP.NET Core project which you have created to support HTTP/2. Right-click on it and select properties, go to debug tab and then enable SSL [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6PBz.png)

Comment: thanks dear @JalpaPanchal. but I'm not using .net core. I'm using wcf or web api.

Comment: but you could try this to enable SSL in visual studio.

Comment: ssl already enabled. not with visual studio but in iis.

Comment: enable it in visual studio and try to check your log

Comment: where can i do that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PhqS.png

Comment: select your project and from the properties window, you could see SSL enabled set to true [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DhKe.png)