# Is it possible to expose WCF services that can be addressed by HTTP/2 ? and how can I do it?

Tags: c#, wcf, http2

I'm trying to know if it's possible to expose WCF services with .Net Framework (<= 4.8) that could be called with http/2.

After some researches, I didn't find any articles telling me it's possible or not possible ?
I can only find this information in comments in the following posts [WCF Webservice does not support HTTP version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623568/wcf-webservice-does-not-support-http-version-2) or [Enable HTTP/2 on WCF and Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58604331/enable-http-2-on-wcf-and-web-api).

And if it's possible how can I do it ?

Comment: Just have a front server that works over http/2 and then have your regular http/1.1 wcf behind.

Comment: _Some_ people would consider WCF to be a _dead_ technology and .Net Framework is hanging on a thread. So, even if it's possible, I'd strongly advise to completely replace the legacy services asap. For that process, building a "Facade" layer first as suggested by Wiktor might actually turn out quite useful to ensure a smooth transition.

Comment: ^^ From the Article ["What Is Windows Communication Foundation"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf) => ["gRPC as an alternative to WCF"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf#grpc-as-an-alternative-to-wcf)

Comment: @Fildor: unfortunately, SOAP based services are enforced by law, e.g. in EU. The .NET Core team did the great work and revived WCF for .NET Core (the [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF)). Since it's officially supported and will be maintained, WCF is no longer *dead*. Sure, if you are free to decide, you could pick up a replacement (like gRPC). But if it's decided anyway, creating a SOAP-based service without WCF (the .NET Framework's WCF or the CoreWCF) could be a nightmare. I would consider WCF as not dead but rather "maintained for compatibility".

Comment: @WiktorZychla _"SOAP based services are enforced by law, e.g. in EU"_ - wasn't aware of that - interesting. So, I'd consider it a "Zombie" (W**Z**F ? haha) ... I also assume, OP may have no other choice than use the legacy but _if_ they do, maybe want to reconsider. Another example why the EU shouldn't be involved in anything "tech" ...

Comment: @WiktorZychla You've clearly understood the situation. In my context, I have no other choices than using WCF with .Net Framework. I'm pretty confident that using and WCF (as HTTP server) and HTTP/2 is impossible but I need to show my bosses a proof (ideally an Microsoft article), saying that ...

Comment: I didn't find an article that directly stated that WCF doesn't support HTTP/2. However, in the comparison article between gRPC and WCF, it can be shown that WCF does not support HTTP/2. [grpc-for-wcf-developers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eBooks/blob/1ed30275281b9060964fcb2a4c363fe7797fe3f3/current/grpc-for-wcf-developers/gRPC-for-WCF-Developers.pdf)